# user-defined function for unsetting session is not working

Tags: php, function, session

I want a simple function where give a session it just echo it and then unset it. I have written something i have written this:

```
function sess_caller($sess){
    if(isset($sess)){
        echo $sess;
    }    
    unset($sess);
}
```

It does echo the session but doesn't unset it afterwards.

Comment: What do you mean _give a session_?  Sessions don't reside in a variable.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a code example of how this function should be used, along with a description of what should happen when the example is executed.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I think that `unset($sess);` would just unset the reference in that case.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: Yes, and passing a reference would make it that it's always SET in the function.

Comment: I want to use it in the html input tag value attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function killSession($key="")
{
 if($key!="" && isset($_SESSION[$key]))
 {
   unset($_SESSION[$key]); //this will empty the key value pair from the 
   $_SESSION (global) variable in php.
 }
 else{
  //if not needed session anymore just destroy it.
  session_destroy();
 }
}
```